# display count of completed events on user level

Tags: user, event

Can we display count of completed events on user level? I tried with Roll up summary field but that field is disabled. Please help.

Comment: What exactly you mean by "User Level"?

Comment: User level here is on user record.

Comment: You can write trigger on Event. Whenever event is completed add logic to count it and reverse if event is deleted or reopen.

Answer (score 1):

You can

1. create a [Summary report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.fundamentals.meta/fundamentals/adg_reports_create_summary_try_it_out.htm) with appropriate chart
2. apply filter to show completed events
3. Once you have the report ready, goto any user record, then press `Edit Layout` as shown below [image]
4. Finally add that report chart into User layout.

> **Edit**

As the OP mentioned in the comment that report won't do, therefore I am posting two more solutions on the basis of that, although I do question the logic behind not accepting this solution as it is simple, fast, and detailed. As it does present a solution to above mentioned problem, therefore, I am going to keep this solution as part of the answer.

> **Custom Solution No.1**

- Create a **number** field on User object, name it `Completed Events` or whatever that suits you.
- Write an [apex trigger](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers.htm) on **Event** with `afterUpdate` event
- Check if the event's **Status** that fired the trigger, to be **completed**
- Get the **Assigned User** of the Event, and add `1` to that field for every event in the trigger with **Completed** status.
- Finally, drop that field, you created in step-1, on User page layout.

> **Custom Solution No.2**
>   There is very nifty custom rollup summary solution out there, and the best part, it's FREE! It is called [DLRS](https://github.com/afawcett/declarative-lookup-rollup-summaries).

- Install the package in your org and it allows you to create custom rollups even on objects that are in **Lookup** relationships.

Comment: Thanks Mahmood for reply. My client dont want report or dashboard for this. Is it possible to roll up count of completed events in User record?

Comment: Well, you can't use standard rollup functionality, but I have edited my answer and included two custom solutions. Kindly check them out.